# Is there a method to run an ioncube protected code on a local development machine?

Tags: magento, plugins

I have bought a magento extension which uses ioncube protection so that it could be licenced for a particular domain only. However, I need to customize it on my local development machine before putting it online on the server. So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to run it on local machine because it normally throws a permission error.
2. After modifying the code, would I be able to put the modified code on the server so that it works correctly as it is ioncube protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IonCube loader is free, you simply have to download it and install it on your local development environment.

If you have the loader installed on your local machine, then the issue is likely a license file that is checked by the encrypted code. If this is the case, and you legitimately bought the extension, you should be able to contact the developer and get them to add a development host name to the license. I know Unirgy have done this for us in the past. Alternatively developers will sometimes already include a check for localhost to allow for development, so if you are using a different domain name locally, changing it to localhost may solve the issue.

You should not be changing any files (other than a license provided by the developer), so putting the code back up into production shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Every module I've ever bought has had as a conditional term for purchase, the requirement that a developer domain key be provided. I have not had anyone refuse that I've asked. They understand that their software needs to be tested for compatibility and function before being released to live sites

Comment: Right! I've contacted the developer regarding the same and he is creating a license to test and modify the code on the local machine. Thanks all. Also, anyone has an idea how to modify such a code that you cannot alter or append to, because of the protection.??

Comment: It will depend on what the module is, and which parts are encoded. Modifying the parts that are encoded will be extremely tricky.

Comment: The code does install but does not work correctly on the local machine.I tried installing thrice on different machines. I have installed it on the server and it works there correctly! However, I cannot edit files on the server directly. What to do in such a case??